# Unable to save class that extends ParseObject

Tags: android, parse-platform

Im trying to save the ParseObject. And while the class is being created on Parse, the values and required rows dont seem to be getting added.

**ParseDetailsItem**

```
@ParseClassName("ParseDetailsItem")
public class ParseDetailsItem extends ParseObject
{

private String fName;
private String lName;
private int age;

    public ParseDetailsItem(String fName,String lName,int age)
    {
        super();

        this.fName = fName;
        this.lName = lName;
        this.age   = age;
    }
}
```

**save()**

```
    s_fName = et1.getText().toString();
    s_lName = et2.getText().toString();
    s_age   = Integer.parseInt(et3.getText().toString());

    ParseDetailsItem t = new ParseDetailsItem(s_fName,s_lName,s_age);

    t.setfName(s_fName);
    t.setlName(s_lName);
    t.setAge(s_age);

    t.saveInBackground();
```

Previously i'd been saving it like this and that seemed to work:

```
    pObject = new ParseObject("Details");
    pObject.put("fName",s_fName);
    pObject.put("lName",s_lName);
    pObject.put("Age",s_age);
    pObject.saveInBackground();
```

I guess im missing the put() method somewhere, but not sure where to call it?

**Edit**
This works, but is this the only way?

```
    t.put("fName", s_fName);
    t.put("lName", s_lName);
    t.put("Age", s_age);
```

**Edit2**

Is there a shorter way of doing it rather than calling put for each value? Say if I pass the values to the constructor and call put() just for the ParseObject-Class. Like this:

```
ParseDetailsItem t = new ParseDetailsItem(s_fName,s_lName,s_age);
t.saveInBackground();
```

Answer (score 2):

The subclasses of ParseObject should have only a zero-argument constructor. From the [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#subclasses):

> Subclassing ParseObject
>
> To create a ParseObject subclass:
>
> 1. Declare a subclass which extends ParseObject.
> 2. Add a @ParseClassName annotation. Its value should be the string you
>      would pass into the ParseObject constructor, and makes all future
>      class name references unnecessary.
> 3. Ensure that your subclass has a public default (i.e. zero-argument)
>      constructor. You must not modify any ParseObject fields in this
>      constructor.
> 4. Call ParseObject.registerSubclass(YourClass.class) in your
>      Application constructor before calling Parse.initialize().

Now what you should do is something like this:

```
@ParseClassName("ParseDetailsItem")
public class ParseDetailsItem extends ParseObject
{

    private String fName;
    private String lName;
    private int age;

    public ParseDetailsItem()
    {
        super();
    }

    public void setDetail(String fName,String lName,int age)
    {
        this.fName = fName;
        this.lName = lName;
        this.age   = age;
    }
}
```

and then call it:

```
ParseDetailsItem t = new ParseDetailsItem();
t.setDetail(s_fName,s_lName,s_age);
t.saveInBackground();
```

Let me know if you manage to get it working, in my code the above works just fine

Comment: Yup. It works now by adding the zero-argument constructor . But right now I have to call put() three times, is there a shorter way of doing it?(Ive added it at the end of the question)

Comment: You can add a three parameters setter that set them in a single call. I can extend my answer later  with an example

Comment: I did try using a setter and called a saveInBackground for the class, but that didnt work initially. Its there in the save() method above